# How to get the value of a textarea and pass it to a link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to get the value from a textarea in my Haml file:

```
%p.text-left
  Please provide reason for rejection.
%textarea#RejectionReason.form-control{:rows => "3"}
```

I have the JavaScript to handle this:

```
:javascript
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("RejectionReason").value;
  }
```

The problem is how do I call `myFunction()` such that my `link_to` first runs the function and the result is placed to the variable `myreason`?

```
= link_to (reject_job_order_path(@job_order, :reason => myreason), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-danger') do
  %i.fa.fa-thumbs-down
    Reject
```

This is all inside a modal if that helps, and all of these are in the same `show.html.haml`.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @Gabbar I do have `%script{:src => "/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"}` in the same haml file

Comment: That would be easy syntax with jquery.

Comment: @Gabbar How? Do you know a jquery function to do that? or do you have a code?

Comment: @Have given answer in both ways using javascript and jquery please have a look.

Comment: @Gabbar Thank you very much this was very helpful although copy pasting it doesn't work instantly because my `RejectionReason` was in a model and without a value it therefore always returned nil but a few edits and its now working

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On document ready get value of `RejectionReason` from `textarea`

Using JavaScript syntax:

```
:javascript
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    var rejectReason = document.getElementById("RejectionReason").value;
    var currentRejectJobPath = document.getElementById("reject-job-link").href;
    var jobPathWithReason = currentRejectJobPath + "?reason=" + rejectReason;
    document.getElementById("reject-job-link").href=jobPathWithReason;
  }
```

Using jQuery syntax:

```
:javascript
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var rejectReason = $("#RejectionReason").val();
    var currentRejectJobPath = $("#reject-job-link").attr('href');
    var jobPathWithReason = currentRejectJobPath + "?reason=" + rejectReason;
    $("#reject-job-link").attr('href', jobPathWithReason)
  }
```

Add a `id` on the link and remove the `reason` parameter which will be passed using JavaScript:

```
= link_to (reject_job_order_path(@job_order), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-danger', id: 'reject-job-link') do
  %i.fa.fa-thumbs-down
    Reject
```